# Is there a way to sort different dataframe by columns rather than by the value of the columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, concatenation

I'm new to programming and I'm currently starting with pandas, I would appreciate some help on finding a way to assemble 8 different dataframes that have different and equal columns so that when I concatenate them in one variable it makes sense.

This is what I got so far:

```py
def read_the_files(): 
    dfs = [] 
    for i in range(1,9):
        archivos_csv = archivos_csv = pd.read_csv("DDFF_"+ str(i) +".csv")        
        dfs.append(archivos_csv) 
    df_unido = pd.concat(dfs) 
    return df_unido

result = read_the_files()
```

To make myself more clear, this are the columns of the first 2 dataframes:

```
archivo1=pd.read_csv("BBDD_1.csv")
a = list(archivo1.columns.values.tolist())

archivo2=pd.read_csv("BBDD_2.csv")
b = list(archivo2.columns.values.tolist())
```

Output:

```
['Unnamed: 0', 'index', 'propertyCode', 'numPhotos', 'floor', 'price', 'propertyType', 'operation', 'size', 'exterior', 'rooms', 'bathrooms', 'address', 'municipality', 'district', 'neighborhood', 'url', 'distance', 'description', 'hasVideo', 'status', 'hasLift', 'priceByArea', 'hasPlan', 'parkingSpace']
['Unnamed: 0.1', 'Unnamed: 0', 'index', 'propertyCode', 'thumbnail', 'externalReference', 'numPhotos', 'floor', 'price', 'propertyType', 'operation', 'size', 'exterior', 'rooms', 'bathrooms', 'address', 'province', 'municipality', 'district', 'country', 'neighborhood', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'showAddress', 'url', 'distance', 'description', 'hasVideo', 'status', 'newDevelopment', 'hasLift', 'priceByArea', 'detailedType', 'suggestedTexts', 'hasPlan', 'has3DTour', 'has360', 'hasStaging', 'superTopHighlight', 'topNewDevelopment', 'labels', 'parkingSpace', 'newDevelopmentFinished']
```

As you can see the number of columns is different, the order is different as well and there are some columns that both data frames have.

Thank you for the help :)

I tried to concatenate different csv files but they came back wrong because the columns are not sorted

Comment: If I recall, pd.concat already does an index alignment on the dataframes you are trying to concatenate. That means the order of the columns does not matter so long as they share the same name between dataframes. What is the issue you're having?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that the order of the columns is not the same, I think it should be fine if you try the following code:

```
df = {}
for i in range(1,9): 
  df[i] = pd.read_csv('DDFF_'+str(i)+'.csv')
df_final = pd.concat(df, ignore_index=True)
```

I tested this for two dataframes, output:

```
df[1]:
      longitude  total_rooms  housing_median_age  latitude
0       -122.05       3885.0                27.0     37.37
1       -118.30       1510.0                43.0     34.26
2       -117.81       3589.0                27.0     33.78
...         ...          ...                 ...       ...
2997    -119.70        956.0                10.0     36.30
2998    -117.12         96.0                40.0     34.10
2999    -119.63       1765.0                42.0     34.42
[3000 rows x 4 columns]
-----------------------------------------------------------
df[2]:
       total_rooms  longitude  latitude  housing_median_age
0           5612.0    -114.31     34.19                15.0
1           7650.0    -114.47     34.40                19.0
2            720.0    -114.56     33.69                17.0
...            ...        ...       ...                 ...
16997       2677.0    -124.30     41.84                17.0
16998       2672.0    -124.30     41.80                19.0
16999       1820.0    -124.35     40.54                52.0
[17000 rows x 4 columns]
-----------------------------------------------------------
df_final is:
       longitude  total_rooms  housing_median_age  latitude
0        -122.05       3885.0                27.0     37.37
1        -118.30       1510.0                43.0     34.26
2        -117.81       3589.0                27.0     33.78
...          ...          ...                 ...       ...
19997    -124.30       2677.0                17.0     41.84
19998    -124.30       2672.0                19.0     41.80
19999    -124.35       1820.0                52.0     40.54
[20000 rows x 4 columns]
```

Your code (with a few changes) is fine though:

```
def read_the_files(): 
    dfs = [] 
    for i in range(1,9):
        archivos_csv = pd.read_csv("DDFF_"+ str(i) +".csv")
        dfs.append(archivos_csv) 
    df_unido = pd.concat(dfs,ignore_index = True) 
    return df_unido

result = read_the_files()
```